# The Password reset link from firebase opens app rather than directs to reset webpage: Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebaseui

I use the default action url, and use SignInScreen by firebase_ui_auth plugin. It sends the reset link successfully but the link opens app from email. However, it works normally if i copy and paste the link to a browser such as chrome. How can i let the link go to the reset page rather than app without copy and paste the link?

Also, even though it opens app with the link, the app doesnt recognize DynamicLink.

Another weird thing is that it opens app but the duplicated app. i.e. there are two the same app opened on the device

```
  SignInScreen(
      showAuthActionSwitch: true,
      providers: [
        EmailAuthProvider()
      ],
    );
```

I tried to use my own custom domain as action url but it did not work.
Also tried flutter clean and invalidate cache